# Diagramming tool to edit a binary tree

Tags: diagrams, tree

I would like to create a diagram of a binary decision tree. What free tool will make that easy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) which allows me te specify the tree in its dot language and then generate a visual representation (e.g. gif, jpg) from it.